# Merge clips with playback-speed automation

Tags: premiere, final-cut-pro-x, davinci-resolve, fcpx

I've got two source clips, and I want specific frames to line up across the merged playback sequence.

```
Eg.
 clip1@frame38 & clip2@frame27 >> merge1@frame27
 clip1@frame56 & clip2@frame40 >> merge1@frame56
```

This requires the playback-speed of at least one source clip to be modulated between the synchronization points on the timeline.

I'm using Resolve, but if you know how to do this in fcpx or premiere that's fine too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a novice in Resolve, Premiere, and FCPX, but in case none emerges to write up an in-built or automatic procedure, in your place I would think of it as two ops:

First calculate and apply the correct playback speed adjustment. For your example:
clip1: 56-38 = 18 frames difference, 19 frames inclusive
clip2: 40-27= 13 frames difference, 14 frames inclusive
so to show those frames across the same time span for synchronized playback of both clips, your choices are to
play clip1 at nineteen fourteenths as fast: 19/14 = 1.357 = 135.7% or
play clip2 at fourteen nineteenths as fast: 14/19 = 7.368 = 73.68%

Second, now that they'll both be playing at the correct speed, it's just a matter of aligning any frame you can conveniently match up between clip1 and clip2.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a Fit-to-Fill edit using 4-point editing.

We will assume:

- **Clip1** (38,56) - to be played at 'normal' speed
- **Clip2** (27,40) - to be fitted / re-timed

Perform the 4-Point Edit:

1. Arrange **Clip1** on the timeline with the desired position/duration
2. Set the In and Out points on the timeline (*move playhead on timeline and then key I (in) and O (out)*) - using the positions of the 38th and 56th frame of **Clip1** as reference
3. **Fill-To-Fit Clip2**:

   - Load **Clip2** into the source viewer (*double click it in Media Pool*)
   - Set the In and Out points of **Clip2** in the source viewer (*move playhead on source viewer and then key I (in) and O (out)*) - at its 27th and 40th frame respectively
   - Set the target/destination video track (Click the V*n* of the desired track - which becomes [V1]). If necessary - add a new track first.
   - Add **Clip2** to the timeline using **Shift+F11**. *Or* drag/drop onto the Timeline viewer [Fit to Fill] overlay by either dragging from Source viewer to Timeline viewer (when using dual viewer mode), or from Media Pool to Timeline viewer (when using single or dual viewer mode)